# Save temporary values by memcpy function

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float *stack=NULL, *tmp1=NULL;
    int i;
    
    stack = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*4);
    tmp1 = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*4);
    
    stack[0]=1.0; stack[1]=1.1; stack[2]=1.2; stack[3]=1.3;
    
    memcpy(tmp1,stack,4*sizeof(float));
    
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        
        printf("stack[%d]=%f, tmp1[%d]=%f\n",i,stack[i],i,tmp1[i]);
    }
    
    stack[0]=2.0; stack[1]=2.1; stack[2]=2.2; stack[3]=2.3;
    
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        
        printf("stack[%d]=%f, tmp1[%d]=%f\n",i,stack[i],i,tmp1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
stack[0]=1.000000, tmp1[0]=1.000000                                                                                                                                                
stack[1]=1.100000, tmp1[1]=1.100000                                                                                                                                                
stack[2]=1.200000, tmp1[2]=1.200000                                                                                                                                                
stack[3]=1.300000, tmp1[3]=1.300000                                                                                                                                                
stack[0]=2.000000, tmp1[0]=1.000000                                                                                                                                                
stack[1]=2.100000, tmp1[1]=1.100000                                                                                                                                                
stack[2]=2.200000, tmp1[2]=1.200000                                                                                                                                                
stack[3]=2.300000, tmp1[3]=1.300000
```

My question is: `memcpy` takes the whole memory location of `stack`, and copy it to `tmp1`. My expectation is that I only need to change `stack`, and therefore `tmp1` will change accordingly. But in this example, `tmp1` does not change as `stack`.

If I want to change `tmp1` as I change `stack`, I need to add one additional line. See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float *stack=NULL, *tmp1=NULL;
    int i;
    
    stack = (float *) malloc(4);
    tmp1 = (float *) malloc(4);
    
    stack[0]=1.0; stack[1]=1.1; stack[2]=1.2; stack[3]=1.3;
    
    memcpy(tmp1,stack,4*sizeof(float));
    
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        
        printf("stack[%d]=%f, tmp1[%d]=%f\n",i,stack[i],i,tmp1[i]);
    }
    
    stack[0]=2.0; stack[1]=2.1; stack[2]=2.2; stack[3]=2.3;
    
    memcpy(tmp1,stack,4*sizeof(float)); /* I add this line here */

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        
        printf("stack[%d]=%f, tmp1[%d]=%f\n",i,stack[i],i,tmp1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then, the results are:

```
stack[0]=1.000000, tmp1[0]=1.000000                                                                                                                                                
stack[1]=1.100000, tmp1[1]=1.100000                                                                                                                                                
stack[2]=1.200000, tmp1[2]=1.200000                                                                                                                                                
stack[3]=1.300000, tmp1[3]=1.300000                                                                                                                                                
stack[0]=2.000000, tmp1[0]=2.000000                                                                                                                                                
stack[1]=2.100000, tmp1[1]=2.100000                                                                                                                                                
stack[2]=2.200000, tmp1[2]=2.200000                                                                                                                                                
stack[3]=2.300000, tmp1[3]=2.300000
```

Does anybody explain why?

Comment: If I give you a photocopy of my book and then I make a change in my original book do you expect the change to magically appear in your copy? No, because once the photocopy (ie `memcpy`) is made then there are two distinct copies.

Comment: Sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is this a learning exercise or do you have something you are actually trying to achieve? Depending on what you are trying to do perhaps you want a pointer to the original `stack` memory rather than a copy (?).

Comment: @kaylum You mean I should use `tmp1 = stack` ?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. But yes, if you do that then any changes to `stack` will be seen when accessed through `tmp1`. Because they would then both point to the same memory. Be sure to do that **after** `stack = malloc()`.

Comment: You allocated 4 bytes for `stack` and `tmp1` but you're expecting to be able to access 4 `float`s at that address.  That's no good because `float` is typically 4 bytes, not 1.  I suppose you meant `malloc(4 * sizeof(float))`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: memcpy takes the whole memory location of stack, and
> copy it to tmp1. My expectation is that I only need to change stack,
> and therefore tmp1 will change accordingly. But in this example, tmp1
> does not change as stack.

The line in question is this:

> ```
>     memcpy(tmp1,stack,4*sizeof(float));
> ```

It copies *the contents* of the memory to which `stack` points into the space to which `tmp1` points.  You now have two independent copies of the data.  It does not make `tmp1` and `stack` aliases of each other.  Naturally, then, if you modify one copy, the changes are not reflected in the other.

> If I want to change tmp1 as I change stack, I need to add one additional line [...]:
>
> ```
>     memcpy(tmp1,stack,4*sizeof(float)); /* I add this line here */
> ```

Yes, you can synchronize the contents of the two blocks of memory at any time by copying the contents of one into the other.  That still doesn't create any aliasing.  The whole thing is analogous to this:

```
int a;
int b;

a = 1;
b = a;

printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
// prints a=1, b=1

a = 2;

printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
// prints a=2, b=1

b = a;

printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
// prints a=2, b=2
```

Assignments such as `a = b` copy *the value* of `b` into `a`, just as `memcpy()` copies the value pointed to by one pointer to the space pointed to by a different pointer.  Subsequently modifying `a` does not then cause the value of `b` to change, just as modifying the values pointed to by `stack` does not cause those pointed to by `tmp1` to change, but of course you can resynchronize any time you want.

If you want to make `tmp1` an alias of `stack` then you want to copy *the pointer*, not the data to which it points:

```
float *stack, *tmp1;

stack = malloc(4 * sizeof(*stack));
tmp1 = stack;  // Now stack and tmp1 point to the same memory

stack[0] = 1.0;
stack[1] = 1.1;
stack[2] = 1.2;
stack[3] = 1.3;

// no memcpy here

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("stack[%d]=%f, tmp1[%d]=%f\n", i, stack[i], i, tmp1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least this problem: **Insufficient memory allocation**

```
stack = (float *) malloc(4);  // Not enough
stack[0]=1.0; stack[1]=1.1; stack[2]=1.2; stack[3]=1.3;
```

Avoid coding the incorrect type with the type-less

```
stack = malloc(sizeof *stack * 4);
if (stack) { // Success
  stack[0]=1.0; stack[1]=1.1; stack[2]=1.2; stack[3]=1.3;
  ...
```

Same for `tmp1`.

---

> My expectation is that I only need to change stack, and therefore tmp1 will change accordingly.

This expectation is not fulfilled with OP's code as there is not connection or linkage between `stack` and `tmp1` other than they happen to have the same data.

Changing one will not change the other.

Comment: Yes. I have corrected this. The results keep the same.